# trac-admin thows Tracback error

Tags: python, trac

I'm have installed Trac on Ubuntu 14.04.1 using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install trac trac-accountmanager trac-graphviz trac-icalviewplugin trac- 
mastertickets trac-wysiwyg trac-wikitablemacro trac-tags trac-customfieldadmin trac- 
datefieldplugin
```

This I believe has install Trac 1.0.1-2, but when I run a simple command such as:

```
$ sudo trac-admin --version
```

I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/trac-admin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Trac==1.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'trac-admin')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/admin/console.py", line 567, in run
    translation.activate(locale)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/util/translation.py", line 325, in activate
    translations.activate(locale, env_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/trac/util/translation.py", line 152, in activate
    t.add(Translations.load(locale_dir, locale or 'en_US',
AttributeError: 'NullTranslations' object has no attribute 'add'
```

I am not familiar with python, any ideas why this is occurring would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue you can either upgrade to [Trac 1.0.2](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDownload), or downgrade to Babel 0.9.6. See [comment:1:ticket:11621](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11621#comment:1) for details.

Comment: Upgrading to Trac 1.0.2 using easy_install did the trick. Many thanks @RjOllos